# How to do incremental data load in ADF from a REST API Source

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, dynamics-business-central

I am a new user of Azure services and I have been using Azure Data Factory to copy data from Microsoft 365 Business Central to an Azure SQL Database. I used the Azure REST API connector to connect to Business Central and did a full data load. Now, I would like to perform an incremental load where any new data recorded in Business Central is to be copied to the SQL Database. I have read about similar questions in the Microsoft community but they were not helpful to me.
I appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have an indicator about the last modified date in your RestAPI response?
In order to do incremental load, you need 2 things : first Last update date and last load date.

Comment: Can you please share an example of the RestAPI response?

Comment: Thanks, @SallyDabbah for your reply. The REST API response is in JSON format, but it's confidential company data so I cannot share it. But yeah the response has a date that indicates the last update date.

Comment: @OsamaAli were you able to implement this? incremental load from REST API?

Comment: Hello @SkyMonster, no, I was not able to implement this approach.

Answer (score 0):

REST API supports pagination . You can copy data from REST API which sends response in Pages when using Azure Data Factory.

[image]

When copying data from REST APIs, normally, the REST API limits its response payload size of a single request under a reasonable number; while to return large amount of data, it splits the result into multiple pages and requires callers to send consecutive requests to get next page of the result. Usually, the request for one page is dynamic and composed by the information returned from the response of previous page.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support

Comment: But the question is about incremental data load(so called delta load) and not pagination. These are two different things.